# Why does this error occur when I try to save a record of my sale in the database?

Tags: django, ajax, postgresql

I am trying to save the details of the sale in the respective tables of the DB, however I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 'id_cliente'
```

Previously, another error related to ajax appeared, which was fixed by adding a few lines of code. But when I started modifying the post method and thus sending the data, it generated this error. I hope you can help ... I need to move forward: /

Views

```
elif action == 'add':

                ventas = json.loads(request.POST['ventas'])
                venta = Venta()
                venta.id_cliente = ventas['id_cliente']
                venta.id_empleado = ventas['id_empleado']
                venta.fecha_venta = ventas['fecha_venta']
                venta.forma_pago = ventas['forma_pago']
                venta.precio_total = float(ventas['precio_total'])
                venta.save()

                for i in ventas['productos']:
                     detalle_venta = Detalle_Venta()
                     detalle_venta.id_venta = venta.id_venta
                     detalle_venta.id_producto = i['id_producto']
                     detalle_venta.cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
                     detalle_venta.subtotal = float(i['subtotal'])
                     detalle_venta.save()
```

JS

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        ventas.items.id_cliente = $('input[name="id_cliente"]').val();
        ventas.items.id_empleado = $('input[name="id_empleado"]').val();
        ventas.items.fecha_venta = $('input[name="fecha_venta"]').val();
        ventas.items.forma_pago = $('input[name="forma_pago"]').val();
        ventas.items.precio_total = $('input[name="precio_total"]').val();

        var parametros = new FormData();
        parametros.append('action', $('input[name="action"]').val());
        parametros.append('ventas', JSON.stringify(ventas.items));
        enviar_productos(window.location.pathname, parametros, function () {
            location.href = 'crear_venta';
        });
    });
```

Models

```
class Venta(models.Model):
    id_venta = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    id_empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_venta = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    forma_pago = models.ForeignKey(Metodo_Pago, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    precio_total = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

   
class Detalle_Venta(models.Model):
    id_detalle_venta = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_producto = models.ForeignKey(
        Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(
        default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Attach your traceback so that developer can understand which line causing the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LdVwsQTy

Comment: your link isn't working

Comment: Try this new link... https://pastebin.com/m7DEmsBP

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you have in ventas['productos'] is not what you expect!
The value inside ventas['productos'] is id_cliente.